# Implement anti-CSRF tokens into all requests to add protection from cross-site request forgery attacks

Tags: security, csrf

Is there any module or technique to implement anti-CSRF tokens into all requests in Drupal 9 for anonymous users?

Answer (score 1):

Drupal [already has CSRF protection for authenticated users](https://www.drupal.org/node/2319205).

One day [core may add support to protect anonymous users as well](https://www.drupal.org/node/1803712).

In the meantime, you could look at the [anonymous token](https://www.drupal.org/project/anonymous_token) module, or force all users to register/log in before using forms on the site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
How can I add a CSRF token not only to forms but also to all custom requests?
Could you please tell me any methods to do that?